# Boolean algebra minimized product of sums to not minimized sum of products

Tags: discrete-mathematics, boolean-algebra

How is that:

(!B AND D) OR (!C AND B) OR (!C AND D)

Equal to that:

(B AND !C) OR (!B AND D)

For the life of me I cannot figure it out, been trying for a good few hours.

The original problem was to convert this minimized product of sums:

(!B OR !C) AND (B OR D)

To sum of products (not minimized).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Adjacency: $(P \land Q) \lor (P \land \neg Q)\Leftrightarrow P$

$(\neg B \land D) \lor (\neg C \land B) \lor (\neg C \land D) \Leftrightarrow$ (Adjacency x 3)

$[(\neg B \land D \land C) \lor (\neg B \land D \land \neg C)] \lor$
$ [(\neg C \land B \land D) \lor (\neg C \land B \land \neg D)] \lor$
$ [(\neg C \land D \land B) \lor (\neg C \land D \land \neg B)] \Leftrightarrow$ (Association, Commutation (i.e. reorder))

$ [(\neg C \land B \land D) \lor (\neg C \land D \land B) \lor (\neg C \land B \land \neg D)] \lor$
$ [(\neg B \land D \land C) \lor (\neg B \land D \land \neg C) \lor (\neg C \land D \land \neg B)] \Leftrightarrow$ (More reordering)

$ [(B \land \neg C \land D) \lor (B \land \neg C \land D) \lor (B \land \neg C \land \neg D)] \lor$
$ [(\neg B \land D \land C) \lor (\neg B \land D \land \neg C) \lor (\neg B \land D \land \neg C)] \Leftrightarrow$ (Idempotence ($P \lor P \Leftrightarrow P$)

$ [(B \land \neg C \land D) \lor (B \land \neg C \land \neg D)] \lor$
$ [(\neg B \land D \land C) \lor (\neg B \land D \land \neg C)] \Leftrightarrow$ (Adjacency x 2)

$ (B \land \neg C) \lor (\neg B \land D)$